# NoSuchMethodError when calling a self-created static method in framework

Tags: android, frameworks, robolectric

The version information I am using：

```
Android studio 3.4.2
gradle 5.1.1
SDK 28
JAVA 8
JUnit 4.12
robolectric 4.3
```

I create a new static method "`isDownloadAlertEnabled`" in frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java.

```
public static boolean isDownloadAlertEnabled() {
    boolean isEnabled = true;
    String downloadAlert = SystemProperties.get("persist.downloadalert.enabled");
    if (downloadAlert == null || downloadAlert.isEmpty()) {
        String gms = SystemProperties.get("ro.com.google.gmsversion");
        if (gms == null || gms.isEmpty()) {
            isEnabled = true;
        } else {
            isEnabled = false;
        }
    } else {
        isEnabled = downloadAlert.equals("true");
    }
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "isDownloadAlertEnabled : " + isEnabled);
    return isEnabled;
}
```

make framework.jar

I have made sure that the method "isDownloadAlertEnabled" is already exists in frameworks/base/api/current.txt and out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt

put jar into app/libs

add as library

Now I want to call the new methord "`isDownloadAlertEnabled`"

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class test3 {
    @Test
    public void test333() {
        System.out.println("test333 isDownloadAlertEnabled:" + DownloadManager.isDownloadAlertEnabled());
    }
}
```

But the result is fail: NoSuchMethodError when running

```
[Robolectric] com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.DownloadManager.isDownloadAlertEnabled()Z

at com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333(test3.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I tested with another static method "`getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile`" which is a what the SDK28 originally had. The result is success.

Why can't self-created static method be called but the original SDK static method can be called?
What can I do to make my own method work?

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In android DownloadManager class have no method available isDownloadAlertEnabled.As per your description,you said that you created isDownloadAlertEnabledmethod inside your own class then you should check import package of DownloadManager class.

Comment: The method " isDownloadAlertEnabled " is added in " app\libs\framework.jar!\android\app\DownloadManager.class ".  
The reference is: " android.app.DownloadManager ".  
So, I import the package in test like:  " import android.app.DownloadManager; ".

Comment: I am not sure about Add static method in predifiend class ,Yes i am sure this way in kotlin.